# Select latest N records in BigQuery based on TimeStamp - More Optimized

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, time-series, timestamp, sql-timestamp

I want to pick latest `2` records based on the timestamp column, let's say to perform analysis.
In reality i have huge dataset where i want to pick `n` records for each of my user_n.

If i could hardcode the value, it would have been okay.

```
SELECT * 
FROM
  `project-id`.huge-dataset-id.streaming-data`
WHERE timestamp_column BETWEEN '2015-06-10 14:20' AND '2015-06-10 14:30'
```

But it has to be formulated dynamic.I am not so strong in SQL and BigQyery.Please help.

I need Latest `N` Records

Tried - (Working Solution), Need more optimised Solution.

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM `project-id`.`dataset`.`streaming_data` s1
    WHERE (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM `project-id`.`dataset`.`streaming_data` s2
        WHERE s1.user_n = s2.user_n
            AND s1.timestamp_col <= s2.timestamp_col
    ) <= 2
  )
```

Since, there are too many nested query, the operation is really slow.
Can someone provide an optimised solution.

Data Table as `streaming_data`

```
-------------------------------
| user_n  | timestamp_column  |
|-----------------------------|
| ABC     | 10-Jun-12 14.30   |
| DEF     | 10-Jun-12 14.30   |
| ABC     | 10-Jun-12 14.20   |
| DEF     | 10-Jun-12 14.20   |
| ABC     | 10-Jun-12 14.10   |
| DEF     | 10-Jun-12 14.10   |
| ABC     | 10-Jun-12 14.00   |
| DEF     | 10-Jun-12 14.00   |
```

Expected Output : Latest 2 Records for all user, based on the latest timestamp

```
-------------------------------
| user_n  | timestamp_column  |
|-----------------------------|
| ABC     | 10-Jun-12 14.30   |
| DEF     | 10-Jun-12 14.30   |
| ABC     | 10-Jun-12 14.20   |
| DEF     | 10-Jun-12 14.20   |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `row_number()`.  For instance, to get the most recent records:

```
SELECT sd.* EXCEPT (seqnum)
FROM (SELECT sd.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_n ORDER BY timestamp_column DESC) as seqnum
      FROM `project-id`.huge-dataset-id.streaming-data` sd
      WHERE timestamp_column BETWEEN '2015-06-10 14:20' AND '2015-06-10 14:30'
     ) sd
WHERE seqnum <= 2;
```

If you want two random rows, use `ORDER BY rand()` instead.

The timestamp range is included because that is in the question.  However, to get the two most recent rows, you can remove it.

Comment: I don't wish to specify the timestamp range, can i remove the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: @AmarKumar - It's poor form to ask questions where the answer can be gained simply by ***trying it for yourself***.

Comment: @AmarKumar . . . You can just select the columns you want (drop the `except`).  But this is BQ syntax:  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#modifiers_for_operator.